Hugging Face Datasets .map not working as expected
I'm running a function over a dataset, but when I compute this, I seem to replace my existing dataset rather than adding to it. What is going wrong?
dataset_c = Dataset.from_pandas(df_all[0:100])

That dataset_c looks like:
Dataset({
    features: ['_id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'memail', 'company_phone_number', 'company_name', 'global_id'],
    num_rows: 100
})

My function is:
def concatenate_entities(examples):
 body = ""
 for col in fields_match_list:
   if col in examples:
     #if (examples[col] != ""):
     body +=  examples[col] + "\n "
   else:
     body += "\n "
 return {"text": str(body)}

Now, when I do the map.
dataset_c = dataset_c.map(concatenate_entities)

I get the following:
Dataset({
    features: ['text'],
    num_rows: 100

})

So, instead of adding to existing features, it has replaced the features.

NOTE: This code has not been tested (but it will work).
The issue is that you are only returning a single entry dictionary which replaces the old data. You need to return the modified examples themselves, like this:
examples['text'] = str(body)
return examples

Alternatively, you can manually send other columns as well:
return {"text": str(body), 'first_name': examples['first_name'], # other columns ...}

